# Git unstage without losing merge?

Tags: git, merge, unstage

I have a branch with hundreds of new and different files and I just want to merge a dozen or so of these into my release branch. I tried running a normal git merge with no commit and that automatically staged hundreds of files I don't want (in addition to finding dozens of conflicts that require manual merging.) I then tried to do a git revert to unstage all of the automerged files and just add the ones I want back to the index, but that also aborted the merge and leaves all the conflict markers in the files. I thought I could just run the mergetool but it now doesn't recognize the conflict markers...

Am I going about this the totally wrong way...or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Merge and revert talk about *commits*, staging applies to *the index*. What exactly are you referring to where? It’s not clear what you are doing.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit - but I already like Manzur's answer # 1 below.

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as using `git reset`. I was using `git stash pop` and had a merge conflict and it also staged some files with changes by me and merge. I resolved the conflict and unstaged all the files with the following command:

```
git reset HEAD <file_1> <file_2> ... <file_n>
```

Comment: Actually I found you don't need to specific the file(s), just do `git reset HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit ambiguous. I'll try to rephrase it and answer accordingly. Say you want to merge only the files(file2, file3) from the branchA:

1) Get the tree sha1 of the branch commit:

```
git cat-file -p branchA
```

2) Checkout the changes under that tree for file2 and file3:

```
git reset <sha1> -- file2 file3
```

3) Commit this changes:

```
git commit -m 'Merge of branchA'
```

If you've already message with the staging, do(in case all the needed changes are committed ahead of time):
    git reset --hard

Comment: Manzur- thanks, that's perfect. I'll still need to check for conflicts in these files but I can do that when merging back to the release branch. At least this simplifies the merge to just the files I care about.

Comment: Experimenting with this now... it seems git checkout works better than git reset in your step 2 manzur because then I don't have the original versions showing up as unstaged changes. Also I can just use the branch name instead of the <sha1>. Make sense?

Comment: Sure, you can use sha1 instead of branch name. They're interchangeable for almost all cases(look at the .git/refs/heads/<branchname> it contains sha1).

Comment: regarding `checkout` vs `reset` it depends. `reset` is better when you know what happens on the index and filesystem. `checkout` is more simple, you can checkout a file to other directory and copy-paste the changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Chef Pharaoh's answer, but shorter and more ergonomic:

```
git reset "*"
```

(The quotes are there to avoid shell expansion.)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a branch with hundreds of new and different files and I just want to merge a dozen or so of these into my release branch.

Then make a commit with just those dozen or so files changed, and merge that.

```
git checkout -b frotzybitsoffeature $(git merge-base feature release)
git checkout feature -- thisfile thatfile theseothers/
git commit -m 'selecting the frotzy subset of feature'

git checkout release
git merge frotzybitsoffeature

git checkout feature            # now tell git the frozybits work is all still in feature
git merge frotzybitsoffeature
git branch -d $_
```

Answer (score -1):

To revert an exact merge commit, and making all the changes as staged, below command can be used.

```
git revert -m 1 <commit-hash>
```